# Sorting data from one table to another table

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting

I have the following tables:

1. `main_table`

   - `stu_name`
   - `stu_mark`
2. `mark_table`

   - `s_name`
   - `pos_mark`
   - `neg_mark`

With data:

`main_table`

```
stu_name  stu_mark
--------  --------
Rob        20
sally     -10
Dave       30
Merve     -50
```

Desired Output:

`mark_table`

```
s_name   pos_mark  neg_mark
-------  --------  --------
Rob       20       NULL
Sally     NULL     -10
Dave      30       NULL
Merve     NULL      -5
```

Comment: This site mostly ignores HTML tags in user-entered content - I have reformatted your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
INSERT INTO mark_table
select stu_name s_name,
       case when stu_mark >= 0 then stu_mark end pos_mark,
       case when stu_mark < 0 then stu_mark end neg_mark
from main_table
```

(Assuming you want marks of 0 to be populated in the pos_mark but not the neg_mark column.)